# Query multiple lined data into one

Tags: ms-access

Please excuse my ignorance, I am very, very new to Access

I'd like to query as follows:

I have the following two tables

[image]

[image]

And I'd like the outcome of my query to be as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a CROSSTAB query. Since CROSSTAB requires three fields, will need to calculate field for column header with DCount(). Table1 is not needed in this query.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table2.Field2) AS FirstOfField2
SELECT Table2.Field1
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.Field1
PIVOT DCount("*","Table2","Field1=" & [Field1] & " AND Field2<'" & [Field2] & "'")+1;
```

Comment: I hoped that it could be done in a standard select query, but guess it cannot. Thanks for your help @June7 !!!

Comment: It can be done in a regular aggregate query by using IIf() expressions if you have a limited number of people. I assumed there are more than 3 people involved.